# why is my implementation so slow? (#26 of 99 haskell problems)

Tags: haskell, optimization, combinations

when solving question 26 (" Generate the combinations of K distinct objects chosen from the N elements of a list" ) i came up with the following implementation:

```
combi :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combi 0 _ = [[]]
combi n ys@(x:xs) = [ y:xs' | y <- ys, xs' <- combi (n-1) xs ]
```

one of the solutions suggested is :

```
combinations :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combinations 0 _  = [ [] ]
combinations n xs = [ y:ys | y:xs' <- tails xs
                           , ys <- combinations (n-1) xs']
```

while somewhat similar, the solution provided runs significantly faster than mine.

why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your solution is incorrect. E.g. `combi 2 [1,2]` is `[[1,2], [2,2]]` instead of `[[1,2]]`.
2. Your recursive case always calculates `combi (n-1) xs`, where `length xs == length ys - 1`. In the correct solution, length of `xs'` decreases with every step. This may seem like a small difference, but recursion compounds it.

Comment: just a matter of recursion (+ incorrect solution..) then? nothing to do with tails's strictness or something related to lazy evaluation?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the main reason.